# Facebook comments are all the same for all posts on Blogger

Tags: javascript, facebook, blogger

I currently have this

`<div class='fb-comments' data-href='flower2fruit.blogspot.ca' data-numposts='5' data-width='550'/>`

after

`<b:include data='post' name='post'/>`

in my template .html on blogger.

what do i have to change `data-href='flower2fruit.blogspot.ca'` to in order for each posts to have their own separate comments?

I have searched and i saw reference to old code which tells you how to change for different code with `href` but didn't find where to change `data-href`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: found it: just change `data-href="whateverURL"` to `expr:data-href='data:post.url'`

Comment: I posted my solution in full details here http://flower2fruit.blogspot.ca/2017/04/how-i-added-facebook-comments-to-my.html